# String with number as Variable , Unix C question

Tags: c, string, gcc, ansi-c

I want to use abc1 ,abc2, abc3,abc4,..abc100,as struct variable name. But I don't know how to set this? have no idea.

Can anybody help me out?
Thanks indeed.

Comment: Your question makes very little sense; please clarify.  Do you want 100 different structs, which can be chosen by specifying a string at runtime?

Comment: SORRY,I want use sets of  string as variable name. This string include const string and changeable integer,,from 1 to 100. Hope I made this clear. thanks

Comment: No, you did not make this clear. There is no reason for you to want to do this, and no way for you to accomplish it in C. You want arrays.

Comment: A piece of advice *"How can I <some manipulation> <some programming construct> in <language>?"* is often an ill-formed question, because you have assumed (1) that this is possible in <language> and (2) that this is a good way to accomplish <underling objective>. Much better to say *"I need to accomplish <underling objective> in <language> and I though I could <some manipulation> <some programming construct> but I can't make it work."* because you can get help on two levels:  (a) understanding <language> and (b) solving your *actual* problem.

Comment: Lacking a clarification from the OP, I'm voting to close. With a clarification we could reopen it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like you're looking for an array.

```
typedef struct { 
/* ... */
} whatever;

whatever abc[100];

abc[0] = xxx;
abc[3] = yyy;
```

Comment: I agree with you. I think the concept Andy's grasping for is that of an array, whether an array OF struct or an array WITHIN a struct is indeterminate at this point.

Comment: sorry, I may not made it clear before. Actually, I want ab1, ab2, ab3 as struct name...The difficulty is how to combine const string with different number.Thanks

Comment: @Andy May I ask you how you're gonna initialize them?

Comment: @ruslik: while you can certainly create variables named ab1, ab2, etc., you really don't want to. Using them will be pointlessly painful. Things like that can work well in a lot of scripting languages, but not so much in C.

Comment: @Jerry, I understand it. I was just curious how OP expects to use them.

Comment: *"Actually, I want ab1, ab2, ab3 as struct name..."* @Andy: You almost certainly *don't* want that. Please specify what you need to accomplish (*not* how you think it should be done), because you're probably bringing a mindset to this problem that does not work well in c.